# What is the reason behind lokas in Hinduism?

Tags: belief, worship, history, philosophy

> In the Puranas, and already in the Atharvaveda, there are fourteen worlds, seven higher ones (vyahrtis) and seven lower ones (patalas), viz. bhu, bhuvas, svar, mahas, janas, tapas, and satya above and atala, vitala, sutala, rasaataala, talatala, mahaatala, patala and naraka below.

Source: [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loka#Hindu_tradition).

What are those lokas meant for? As we already have a place called earth and it's possible to do all duties that are performed in those lokas on earth as well, just like we are doing now?

Are those lokas cosmic (which humans can never see) or physical (which we can see, but not with the available technology)?

Comment: each loka has its own characteristics and is suited to people who have those same characteristics. People in Earth have been born, because their karmas, desires and also their tendencies are best suited for this world. A being may be born in a different world if that is the best suited for him. In Autobiography of a Yogi, Chapter 43, the great yogi Sri Yuktheswarji describes a world called Hiranyaloka. There are a number of worlds, both physical and metaphysical. So while Earth provides opportunity to do all duties, it is not suitable for every characteristics. Some beings birth in other loka.

Comment: after death there is life next janma is if next janma same relation same human being s soul take immediate next janma or taking time soul takes how many days to go lokhas

Comment: 1) There are fourteen lokas. Earth being the intermediate
2) there are seven above, six below earth
3) Each loka represents a state of atma at its purity & maturity
4) All pralaya that comes, comes from the bottom of oceans as per scriptures
5) During childhood, thought how come pralaya to come "heavens" then so much rain downpour to flood earth !!!..... suppose the water table from earth increases, it would flood each place, it is aform of pralaya

Answer (score 9):

Sri Swami Sivananda explains correlation between Lokas and Chakras in his book [Kundalini Yoga](http://www.dlshq.org/download/kundalini.htm) and in [this page](http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=473). He says **Lokas correspond to Chakras** of human body.

> Man is a microcosm (*Kshudra Brahmanda*). Whatever exists in the outer
> universe exists in him. All the Tattvas and worlds are within him and
> so is the Supreme Siva-Sakti. The body may be divided into two main
> parts, namely, the head and trunk on the one hand, and the legs on the
> other. In man, the centre of the body is between these two, at the
> base of the spine where the legs begin.
>
> The *Surya Mandal* or the fire is in the *Nabhi* or the navel. The *Chandra
> Mandal* or the sphere of Amrita is a little below Ajna Chakra.
>
> Supporting the trunk and
> throughout the whole body there is the spinal cord. This is the axis
> of the body, just as Mount Meru is the axis of the earth. Hence, man’s
> spine is called *Merudanda*, the Meru or axis-staff. The legs and feet
> are gross which show less signs of consciousness than the trunk with
> its spinal white and grey matter; which trunk itself is greatly
> subordinate in this respect to the head containing the organ of mind,
> or physical brain, with its white and grey matter. The positions of
> the white and grey matter in the head and spinal column respectively
> are reversed.
>
> The body and legs below the centre are the seven lower
> or nether worlds upheld by the sustaining Sakti or Powers of the
> universe. From the centre upwards, consciousness more freely manifests
> through the spinal and cerebral centres. Here there are the seven
> upper regions or Lokas, a term which means “What are seen” (Lokyante),
> that is, experienced, and are hence the fruits of Karma in the form of
> particular rebirth.
>
> *These regions, namely, Bhuh, Bhuvah, Svah, Tapa,
> Jana, Maha and Satya Lokas correspond with the six centres; five in
> the trunk, the sixth in the lower cerebral centre; and the seventh in
> the upper brain or Satyaloka, the abode of the Supreme Siva-Sakti.*

[image: Chakras]

The Chapter [Human Body - A Miniature Cosmos : Departure of Soul to the next Lokas  of Skanda Purana](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/25507/45f_chapter_50_1.pdf) describes this correlation in detail.