# Where is Brahmaloka nowadays?

Tags: brahma, lokas

I want to know that where is Lord Brahma's Brahmaloka nowadays? Was Brahmaloka destroyed or anywhere in this universe?

Comment: "nowadays"?!! Brahmaloka is not a place which changes its position. There are various planetary system located in this Hiranyagarbha and the topmost of them is Satyaloka also known as Brahmaloka. Brahmaloka is not exactly same as Satyaloka though.

Comment: haha..what a funny question..from where you got the info that brahmaloka changes its place with time?

Comment: see my answer to this question - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10465/scientifically-what-is-a-loka